# I was offered a job at one of my clients. Would it be unethical for me to take it?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

TL;DR - I was offered a job at one of my clients. Would it be unethical for me to take it?

I work as a contractor for a person with strong ties in the education industry. He wants to start a new education company and my work has been instrumental. Meanwhile, through him, I have been building my network.

I've been doing some pro bono work for him too since he does, at times, mention I would get a full time high pay job if this works out. I think I will because he needs me.

Recently, he got into a huge conflict with a client. He exploited industry relationships  and also the fact of having me as an expert to squeeze this company. He basically bullied them instead of having an honest conversation, although the points he's been raising are all valid.

Meanwhile, he kept me in the dark about some aspects of the project we were doing for them and I've caught him lying to others and manipulating them. I think he will do this again in the future to have control.

After the conflict, the company that he fought with wants to hire me as an independent expert to bypass him.

On one hand, he told me he wants to use them to fund his own company. On the other hand, I'm tired of getting caught in the middle of his dramas, especially since I know that, if I walk away, he won't be able to use me as leverage. But he could destroy my reputation by influencing his network.

What's a good way to think this through and make a good choice? What should I consider?

Comment: OP, I think there is a good question in here but as written it's quite confusing and hard to follow (and probably likely to attract down votes although I haven't downvoted it). Are you willing for me to suggest some edits to the text to hopefully make it easier for people to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to emphasize newer understanding:

***There is no ethical issue here.*** After reading your comments in reply to [schizoid04's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/149574/2317) I see that you're not an employee of this guy, but are working on a contract to contract basis and there is not currently a contract between him and you. Now you've been offered a contract (or job) by a different organization. You have no obligation to him. Would you expect him to pay you if he never has more work for you? If the guy had wanted to keep you for himself, he should have made you an employee with a contractual clause preventing such a move.

It is not that uncommon for employees of one company to go to work for a client of that company (the other way around happens too). For example, accountants who work for auditing companies sometimes get hired as CFO's of companies they audit. Employees of consulting companies are hired by clients after the individual had done consulting for the client company through his/her old employer. In government work it isn't uncommon for employees of contracting companies to become employees of the governmental agency they have supported. I've rarely heard the people who change jobs like this called unethical.

A substantial part of your unhappiness with your current boss seems to be that you disapprove of his tactics on ethical grounds. You might want to consider what is happening to your reputation while you work for him - if people don't trust him, they  may think they can't trust you either. Getting away from him may actually improve your reputation.

Even beyond that, it seems to me this is not an ethical issue. You've been offered a new job and seem unhappy with the person for whom you currently work. At its heart, the question - at least IMO - should be would you be happier (and that could include financial issues) with the newly offered job than your current one.

In other circumstances there might be legal issues. However, that does not seem to be the case here. Furthermore, it is beyond the scope of this site in most cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to write a response and it was very helpful! I was struggling with it for a few days, but I am convinced now that taking it would be the best decision for me.

Comment: @user112640: Glad to help. I hope it works out well for you.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're asking specifically, whether you should take this job with your client and leave the company you're at now.

What I would say is, legally, you should check whether you have a contract or other agreement with your existing employer that would prevent you from competing and/or working with their clients. This is a pretty standard provision and I'd be surprised if they didn't have the forethought to make you sign something to this effect.

Otherwise.... If it were me, I would do it. Though it's impossible for us to answer questions like 'what should i do' or what's best for you, or to provide general advice.

To be direct, it is generally considered unethical to leave to work with one of your clients. There are personal factors that you should consider, such as whether you have a legal agreement barring this, whether you dislike the company you're with currently enough to do so, how much you'd want to work for the client, how much they're offering to pay, etc. It's up to you whether you decide it's worth them saying negative things about you to their peers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, and sorry for the unclear wording (thanks for editing this!) I am not a full-time employee. I have signed two service contracts for two reports, which I completed successfully. But he's been using my name to force the company to give his future company a bigger contract. He basically says " I have this expert, so give us money!" It's a tricky situation.

Comment: Anti-competing provisions should only be accepted only in managerial positions or higher bracket salary levels, and should always carry a high compensation attached. Otherwise, they should not be accepted. Whether people accepts commonly them or not, is of no concern.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, re-read **ALL** agreements you have with your current employer.  If you honestly believe you have no contractual restriction on this move, then it is well worth having an attorney review these documents, as well.  The company asking to hire you may very well be willing to pay your costs on this, as it protects them, as well.  Do **NOT** let their "company lawyer" do it for you.  Their lawyers work for them, not for you.

It is not up to us ("The Internet") to tell you what job you should or should not take.  I will offer only my experience:  People like your current employer tend to do well in the short term, but fail long term, as their network of people willing to work with them will grow smaller and smaller over time.  In addition, they will use people such as yourself as "ablative armor" and scapegoat you out when serious problems occur.

Beyond that, you must make your own decisions.  Your position may be very lucrative, short-term, but you will "wear the stain" of your current company's failure when (not if) it happens if you're still with them when it falls apart.